# Using typescript to create HTML using template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dynamic-html

Trying out typescript, I want to achieve the following thing:

Getting a question text and a number from server and displaying it in DOM somewhere, using typescript.

Currently I have the following .ts file:

```
class QuestionResponse {
    constructor(public questionText, public questionNumber) {
    }
}
function questioner(question: QuestionResponse) {

    return '<div data-val-id="${QuestionNumber}"> ${QuestionText} </div>';
}

var testQuestion = new QuestionResponse("Question text number 5", 5);

//this will be replaced by .innerHTML of some element:
alert(questioner(testQuestion));
```

This does not replace the ${QuestionNumber} with the question.QuestionNumber... nor the Text. I don't want to use string appends, I want to use clean html, preferably on a seperate .html file.

Basically I'm asking:
Is it possible using typescript, if yes, how?
If not, what would be the best practice way to achieve this using angularjs? (but still using typescript)

Comment: In order to use the string template feature you have to use backticks (same key as `~`) instead of the single tick `'`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
function questioner(question: QuestionResponse) {
    return `<div data-val-id="${question.questionNumber}"> ${question.questionText} </div>`;
}
```

The important part here is the usage of ` (backquote/backtick)
**Wrap your string with ` instead of " and '** to make use of the `${}` syntax.

This is a TypeScript (and ES6) feature.

Comment: K tnx, that did the trick, is it possible to use this `...html...` on an external html file?

Comment: You can only use this feature within the context of a string in typescript, or ES6. However if you use an *IDE* such as *webstorm*, it will detect that you're composing an HTML string and will "treat" it as such. Also in *webstorm*, you can press **alt+enter** to access additional related features.